# Display empty line for non existing fields with jq

Tags: jq

I have the following json data:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"hostmacroid":"2392","hostid":"10953","macro":"{$GATEWAY}","value":"10.25.230.1"}],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"hostmacroid":"1893","hostid":"12093","macro":"{$GATEWAY}","value":"10.38.118.1"}],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"hostmacroid":"2400","hostid":"14471","macro":"{$GATEWAY}","value":"10.25.230.1"}],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"hostmacroid":"799","hostid":"10798","macro":"{$GATEWAY}","value":"10.36.136.1"}],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"hostmacroid":"1433","hostid":"10857","macro":"{$GATEWAY}","value":"10.38.24.129"}],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"hostmacroid":"842","hostid":"13159","macro":"{$GATEWAY}","value":"10.38.113.1"}],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[],"id":1}
```

I am trying to extract the value of the "value" field from each line. `jq -r '.result[].value' <jsonfile>` works perfectly but it does not take into account the JSON lines where there is no "value" field. I would like it to print an empty line for them. Is this possible with jq?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
jq -r '.result[].value // "" ' a.json
```

This uses the *or* operator `//`. If `.result[].value` is present, the value will get printed, otherwise an empty line gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
jq -r '.result | if length > 0 then .[0].value else "" end'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `false // X` and `null // X` produce X, `.result[].value // ""` may not be what you want in all cases.

To achieve the stated goal as I understand it, you could use the following filter:

```
.result[] | if has("value") then .value else "" end
```